# TextInput Not Accepting Keyboard Input (Kivy)

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy

I've been trying to build a simple GUI using Kivy on a Raspberry Pi running Raspian Jessie. But I'm having some issues...

My TextInput isn't accepting *any* keyboard input, but it *is* focusing when I click inside the text input box (with a blinking cursor and all). This isn't an issue with my keyboard, because I can successfully interrupt the program with Ctrl-C.

I suspect there might be an issue with TextInput being placed inside a BoxLayout, but if I didn't do that, the TextInput would take up the entire screen. If the BoxLayout is the issue, then how could I limit the size of the TextInput (since apparently size_hints don't do anything). Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code. For simplicity, I've decided to separate out my code into .py and .kv files:

gui.kv

```
#:kivy 1.4
#:import turn_on led_controller.turn_on
#:import turn_off led_controller.turn_off
#:set Iset 100

FloatLayout:
    ToggleButton:
        id: on_off_switch
        text: "ON" if self.state == 'down' else "OFF"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y': 0.2}
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        on_state: turn_on(app.ser, Iset) if self.state == 'down' else turn_off(app.ser)
    Button:
        text: "TODO: Graph"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: 0.7, 0.3
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.9}
        size_hint: 0.7, 0.1
        TextInput:
            id: textbox
```

gui.py

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class GUI(App):
    from led_controller import init_serial
    ser = init_serial()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('gui.kv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

Comment: I can write into the TextInput, after removing the imports in the kv file. Additionally, '_rom led_controller import init_serial;ser = init_serial()_ should after if __name__ == '__main__': and before GUI().run(). Why are these imports in the kv file?  All these imports in the py file are 
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.label import Label  you just need the one for builder and app

Comment: Placing it in a BoxLayout is not the issue.

Comment: The reason I've got the imports in my Kivy file is because I reference those functions in my on_state. I know that that part works; it's just the text box I'm having problems with. I also know I've got unnecessary imports in the Python file (I had previously been doing it all in the py file), but I don't think those should be responsible.